# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I fetched location:[] from monogodb and then encoded it in json and printed it on the screen. Here is the output:

```
{"57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e":{"_id":{"$id":"57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e"},"location":[33.7715,72.7511]}}
```

Now the problem is that I'm trying to get only location from this JSon so I decoded it. Here is the code:

```
  echo $arr= json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor));
  $j= json_decode($arr,true);
  var_dump( $j->location);
```

var_dump is returning null. Moreover it displays the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

PS: I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: should be `json_decode($arr);` or `json_decode($arr,false);` check [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) Manual

Comment: tried it. Still returns null and the error is Undefined property: stdClass::$location

Comment: Can you print_r($j) and check what value in $j.

Comment: @Sk_ This is what it prints:: object(stdClass)[6]
  public '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public '_id' => 
        object(stdClass)[8]
          public '$id' => string '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e' (length=24)
      public 'location' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => float 33.7715
          1 => float 72.7511

Comment: I want to get location from this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$j->location` is still not valid. you can get the location in the following 2 methods

your location is `$j->57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e->location`

```
$arr = '{"57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e":{"_id":{"$id":"57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e"},"location":[33.7715,72.7511]}}';
$j= json_decode($arr);
$x = '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'; 
var_dump( $j->$x->location); 
// if you don't want to declare $x
var_dump( $j->{'57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'}->location);
```

or using array method

```
$j = json_decode($arr, true);
var_dump( $j['57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'][location]);
```

Comment: How can I get rid of this : '57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'

Comment: This one worked : var_dump( $j->{'57237036d89c45e1e3fda94e'}->location);

Comment: that is there in your json string, you may need to change that

Comment: I'm using mongodb in which I just inserted location. When I retrieved it this is what I get with it :p